# Switching to Other Database in Hibernate When the Primary Fails

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using hibernate for fetching the data from database .  We have oracle RAC database with 20+ nodes .

Now the problem is , if one node of the database fails , I have to switch to the other node , at runtime without the application throwing an error and if that node is down i have switch to the 3rd node like wise .

When we are using legacy JDBC style of establishing connection , it can be done pretty easy , because connection object will be null , when the connection to the node fail

This is the way i am creating session factory ,

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

```
  private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() 
  {
       try 
       {
       return new Configuration().configure("database.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
       }
  }
```

and this is the way am getting session,

session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

Now , how can i identify that the node went down , so that i can try connecting to the alternative node .

I can't use the below type of configuration , because all my node sid's are different

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=(load_balance=on)(failover=on)       (address=(protocol=tcp)(host=host1)(port=1521))(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=host2)(port=1521)))(connect_data=(service_name=xxxxsid)(failover_mode=(type=select)(method=basic)))
```

I am scratching my head from 2 days to figure out how can i achieve this .

Comment: Due to the issues of ensuring consistency between the multiples copies, I strongly suggest that you rely in the DBMS for redundancy/high availability and avoid switching from your app manually.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help, but there is another Oracle JDBC driver which is just proper for RAC. I have not worked with it, but I believe that JDBC driver shall accept multiple database URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that when you open a session you should make an assertion ( Java assertion ) , such as read session state ( Read Only  or something ) this way you can check weather the connection is active or not , based on assertions you can try getting different session for another node.

This link might help you a bit (making assertions ):

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1001337

Hope it helps ;-)

Comment: Hi , Thanks all for the reply , when i call the connection method on session object , eclipse was complaining that the method is obselete , i tried a diff approach .   I included the session.createSQLQuery method call in try block and if the conneciton is stale , it will throw "Connection could not possible" error , and in the exception block i again created a nested catch block , where i am trying to connect to other node